# NoClassDefFoundError in java command line

Tags: java, command-line

I am using command line to run java file. Here's my files:

```
Class files: workspace/test/src/test/test.class   
Java files: workspace/test/src/test/test.java
```

My command line is (CLASSPATH is already setted):

```
D:\Twitter\workspace\test\src\test>java test
```

And my error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test (wrong name: tes
t/test)
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please post `test` class?

Comment: To completely know where the `test` class compiles to we would need to know what command was used to compile it due to the `-d` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
D:\Twitter\workspace\test\src\test>cd ..
D:\Twitter\workspace\test\src>java test.test
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the fully qualified class name (FQCN) to the `java` command. Your class is named `test` (`Test` as a class name would be better) and is in the package `test`. Therefore the FQCN is `test.test`.

To start your program you have to call `java test.test`. from `D:\Twitter\workspace\test\src`.